# Android Moto G5 Bands: Will handset purchased in India work in Greece / Turkey?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, baseband

I have an Android Moto G5.  The specs show the following bands but will all handsets support all bands? Or is this a superset of all supported bands in the Model but the actual ones depend on where the handset is sold?

[image]

I ask because I am going to be travelling to Turkey (Istanbul) and Greece (Athens), both nations I've not been to before and wanted to confirm that my handset will work on the cellular frequencies in use on networks there. If it matter, this handset was purchased in India (see version details below)

Also, if it matters the roaming will be on Vodafone network in both nations.

Any other way to verify which frequencies are actually supported by the handset I own and whether the Greek and Turkish networks will support them?

Is there any way to get more info on my specific Baseband version of the signal chip?

```
Version: PVT1
SKU: XT1677
Baseband version: M8937_11.16.02.51R CEDRIC_INDIADSDS_CUST
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a list of all bands your phone supports. So all you left to do is to do check what bands cellular provider operates. Here the links for [Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators_of_the_Middle_East_and_Africa#Turkey) and [Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators_of_Europe#Greece) operators.

So the answer is it should work on 4G and 3G fine.

To get the phone specs you can consult sites like [PhoneArena](https://www.phonearena.com) or [GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/). You need to look up by your phone specific model (`XT1677` in your case), and not by its commercial name, because sometimes specific countries (especially India) receive a slightly changed model, that has same name.

Comment: The main motivation behind checking was that I've a friend who recently traveled to USA with the same phone and it *apparently* did not work there. Was unexpected to me. I assumed these days most phones support all the common bands for USA. And this model seems to support a lot of bands.

Comment: In the US, Sprint, Verizon and US Cellular use CDMA. AT&T and T-Mobile use GSM. Most of the rest of the world uses GSM. So he could be in the area without good GSM coverage.

Comment: Yes. That explains the US troubles. CDMA is a wholly different beast.

Answer (score 1):

GSMArena tends to list and mix the data of multiple variants together ("superset" in your own words). Using the individual variant data from [PDAdb](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=11344&c=motorola_moto_g5_dual_sim_td-lte_16gb_xt1677__motorola_cedric), and the same list posted by @igrinis , I present a different conclusion: it will generally have poor LTE support.

- Referring to another list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LTE_networks_in_Europe) that specifically talks about LTE in Europe, it can be seen that B7 and B20 are used heavily (especially B20 - a signature of European-variant phones). The XT1677 variant lacks both.
- There actually is a variant of Moto G5 that specifically marks itself as "Moto G5 Dual SIM TD-LTE **EU** JP AU" with the model number of [XT1676](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=11329&c=motorola_moto_g5_dual_sim_td-lte_eu_jp_au_16gb_xt1676__motorola_cedric), and it covers European bands fully. This is the variant supposed to be sold/used in EU/JP/AU regions.

Comment: Do keep in mind that, even nowadays, band support is still hit-or-miss for most Android phones, especially low- and mid-rangers.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of detail  I was worried about. So will it just mean that my handset will degrade to a lower level of data network? Or are you suspecting I won;t even connect to the networks in Turkey at all for data? Is at least voice calling a given with my handset?

Comment: Since being connected is reasonably critical for me on this trip I am debating buying another backup handset. If I verify that the model supports B7 & B20 is that fairly sufficient? Anything else to look for? What makes for a"universal" handset these days? Or close to it.

Comment: Why is band support so "hit or miss", as you put it? Is it difficult to pack in all the common bands into the baseband chip? Or is there virtually no notion of "common" any more with so much of band proliferation?

Comment: Are the bands in rest of EU substantially different from the B7 & B20 you mentioned for Turkey / Greece? Reason I ask is that a few months ago I traveled with this same phone through Spain /Germany / Italy / France / Switzerland but never had a problem? Or is there a chance that that the info on PDAdb is actually not an exact match for my handset?

Comment: According to a  link you provided, `XT1677` supports LTE on bands 1,3,5,8,40.  Turkish Vodafone operates on 3,7,8,20. So at least two  bands supported. All other Turkish operators also support band 3.

Comment: @igrinis Thanks! So the situation may not be totally bleak then? I will have *some* band support just not as good a coverage as I may have had in a perfect world?

Comment: @igrinis I included the alternative European LTE list for a reason - B3 is generally marked as "partially in use / shared" and B8 is "not in use". Per theory, lower frequency bands are to provide more coverage and thus B20 (800) is key to getting ubiquitous LTE access.

Comment: @curious_cat 2G/3G should still work alright - pentaband WCDMA has been around for a long while. You could just refer to the lists we provided in our answers for the bands you need, but from my own perspective whenever I see people ask about European support, B20 is always the center of the question.

Comment: @curious_cat The SoC/baseband is technically capable of most bands, but cramming in high-performance antennas/peripherals for TX/RX operation on each band can be forbidden by cost. Right now the most surefire bets on band coverage are from Apple, Huawei (Mate series), Samsung (S/Note series), and the new Mi Mix 2, and before you even check, they're all costly.